# [WCF][IsReference=true] Compare objects of the same instance

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, equals

I'm developing a WCF Service and using Entity Framework (EF) to model my database into objects.

I've also built my own objects to extend the EF objects, in order to provide custom features and not be "hostage" of any update to the EF model.

So, the thing is, imagine two childs with the same parent (that is, the parent have the same Id but are not the same object in the memory). When I see the generated SOAP message It's not using the IsReference property because WCF cannot realize that the objects should be the same.

I've tried to override Equals an ReferenceEquals but no luck what so ever.

Any suggestion?

Best regards,
jpsfs

Example:

```
    [DataContract(Name = "Parent", IsReference = true)]
    public sealed class Parent 
    {

        [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
     }

    [DataContract(Name = "Child")]
    public sealed class Child 
    {

        [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "Parent")]
        public Parent Parent{
            get;
            set;
        }

     }
```

Comment: I had this problem to with the slight difference that I referenced the class itself as a child, but could not figure it out too. I ended up manually assigning them by reference instead of id. Don't know any other solution though.

Comment: @Silvermind how did you manually assign them? I'm doing something like Child.Parent = new Parent(entityFrameworkChild.T_Parent). The problem here is using the "new" but I'm not seeing any other way of doing this.

Comment: You would have to create a flat list with all items and then manually assign each and everyone to each other. Best way to do it would be to make a method in the 'wcf class' like `MyChildClass.AddChild(children)` and then loop through all and set it's parent to `this` and keep on running down the tree. When I have time i will put an example together. Probably in about a couple of hours.